# how to validate the entered date when mouse blur

Tags: jquery, html

How to validate the inputed date when mouse blur? If the entered date is incorrect then show the current date in textbox

```
<p>Date:
<input id="datepicker" type="text">
</p>
<script>
$("#datepicker").datepicker();
</script>
```

my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kannankds/uWwtc/

Comment: What do you mean by incorrect date? the format?

Answer (score 2):

use blur function to do that

`$("#datepicker").on('change',function(){ your code});`

**[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/uWwtc/3/)**

Comment: Iam not trying to alert.How to display current date on textbox if the key board entered date is wrong

Comment: @kannan just was just the sample alert you can put your code there.

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this:

```
$("#datepicker").on('blur',datepicker);
```

But I would recommend you to use change instead of blur:

```
$("#datepicker").on('change',datepicker);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also do this:

```
<p>Date:
<input id="datepicker" type="text" onblur="check()">
</p>

<script>   
 function check()
 {
     //put validations here
  }
</script>
```